# Printing data from a loop in multiple place without running the loop again

Tags: php, loops

Lets I have an array like this

```
$age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");

<?php 
 $age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
?>
    <div id="3">
          <!-----result of foreach loop---->
    </div>
    <div id="1">
         <?php 
            foreach ($age as $key => $value) {?>
                    <p><?php echo $value;?></p>
            <?php
            }
         ?>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <!-----result of foreach loop---->
    </div>
<?php
?>
```

I want to print the same result in `<div id="2">` and in `<div id="3">`   , without loop through the array in  , I just want to  use the loop only for one time .

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve by not having multiple loops? You could concatenate your loop into a variable and echo it in multiple places.

Comment: If I have an array of million items , then surely my script will be slow .

Comment: Your browser will be worse ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?php 
            $pAge = "";
            foreach ($age as $key => $value) {
               $pAge .= "<p>" . $value . "</p>";
            }
 ?>

    <div id="3">
          <?= $pAge; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="1">
          <?= $pAge; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting all of them in a variable and then echo them out.
Something like this -

```
<?php 
 $age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
 $display_str = "";
 foreach ($age as $key => $value) {
    $display_str .= $value;
 }
?>
<div id="1">
  <?php echo $display_str;?>     
</div>
<div id="2">
    <!-----result of foreach loop---->
    <?php echo $display_str;?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just store the html before the div part and print it three times:

```
<?php 
    $age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");

    $htmlString = '';
    foreach ($age as $key => $value) 
    {
        $htmlString .= '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
    }
?>

<div id="3">
   <?=$htmlString?>
</div>
<div id="1">
   <?=$htmlString?>
</div>
<div id="2">
   <?=$htmlString?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like as:

```
<div id="1">


 <?php 
        $html="";
        foreach ($age as $key => $value) {


                $html .= "<p>".$value."</p>";
                }
               echo $html;
                ?>

</div>
<div id="2">
    <?php echo $html; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you echoing $html in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just store the result values in array in use in anywhere like this:

```
<?php 
$age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
?>
    <div id="3">
          <!-----result of foreach loop---->
    </div>
    <div id="1">
         <?php 
            $res = array();
            foreach ($age as $key => $value) {?>
                    <p><?php 
                    $res[] = $value;
                    echo $value;?></p>
            <?php
            }
         ?>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <!-----result of foreach loop---->
        <?php
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($res); ?>
        <p><?php 
            echo $res[0];
            echo $res[1];
            echo $res[2];
        ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using :

```html
<?php 
  function myfunction($value,$key)
  {
      echo "$value<br>";
  }

 $age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
?>
    <div id="3">
         <?php array_walk($age,"myfunction"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="1">
        <?php array_walk($age,"myfunction"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <?php array_walk($age,"myfunction"); ?>
    </div>
```